# scroll on overflow if the children count is more than a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to add scroll on the `<ul>` element if the number if `<li>`s is more than a particular number.
Let's say we have 12 children. I would like to show 7 of them and scroll the remain.

This is what I try:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.ul-scrollable, ol.ul-scrollable").each(function (key, val) {
    max_num = $(this).attr('data-maxVisible') || 8;
    //console.log(max_num);
    var lis = $(this).children('li');
    if(lis.length > max_num) {
      maxHeight = 0;
   for(i = 0; i <  max_num; i++) {
       maxHeight += +$(lis[i]).outerHeight(true);
       //console.log(maxHeight);
      }
      $(this).css({'max-height' : maxHeight + 'px', 'overflow-y' : 'auto'});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  background: white;
  width: 70px;
}
ul li {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-scrollable" data-maxVisible="7">
<li>li1</li>
<li>li2</li>
<li>li3</li>
<li>li4</li>
<li>li5</li>
<li>li6 li6 li6</li>
<li>li7</li>
<li>li8</li>
<li>li9</li>
<li>li10</li>
<li>li11</li>
<li>li12</li>
<li>li13</li>
</ul>
```

But, the calculation for Height is not applicable correctly.

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ofr79tfb/1/)

Answer (score 4):

An easier way of accomplishing the same effect is to grab the 7th index's distance from the top and then setting the `max-height` to that.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.ul-scrollable, ol.ul-scrollable").each(function (key, val) {
    var distance = $(this).children('li').eq(7).offset().top;
    $(this).css({'max-height' : distance + 'px', 'overflow-y' : 'auto'});
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  background: white;
  width: 70px;
}
ul li {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-scrollable" data-maxVisible="7">
<li>li1</li>
<li>li2</li>
<li>li3</li>
<li>li4</li>
<li>li5</li>
<li>li6 li6 li6</li>
<li>li7</li>
<li>li8</li>
<li>li9</li>
<li>li10</li>
<li>li11</li>
<li>li12</li>
<li>li13</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. But, that is not accurate either. Also, if there be any element before UL, that would affect too.